# Is it possible to display native component in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

If I want to show a native component such as Google Map, WebView, etc. in my Flutter app, Is it possible?
If not, May It have in future?

Comment: It's in the making, at least for Android: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/debd50158e643e60722e86d51f0d47bdf061492c

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom plugins for native. read the detail [here](https://proandroiddev.com/build-your-own-plugin-for-flutter-cfee1a08ea3a).